# Translate column values based on string match

Tags: r

I have a dataframe called `mydf`. `mydf` has values in every column with either 1 letter or 2 letters. I want to replace those values with `0/0` if it is one of `zero.zero` vector elements and `0/1` if is one of the elements from `zero.one`. And nothing if it is NA or any other character combinations.

```
zero.zero<-c("A","T","G","C")
zero.one <-c("AG","AT","AC","GA","GC","GT","TA","TC","TG","CT","CG","CA")

the code would look something like this:
 translation <-function(x){
       if (mydf[,x] == zero.zero){
                  mydf[,x]<-"0/0"
                      }else{
        if (mydf[,x]==zero.one)){
                  mydf[,x]<-"0/1"
        }
      }
    }      


mydf

Ap   Bp   Cp
A    AT   GA
A         GT
A    AG   G


result

Ap      Bp   Cp
0/0    0/1   0/1
0/0          0/1
0/0    0/1   0/0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
tab<-stack(list("0/0"=zero.zero,"0/1"=zero.one))
mydf[]<-lapply(mydf,function(x) tab$ind[match(x,tab$value)])
#   Ap   Bp  Cp
#1 0/0  0/1 0/1
#2 0/0 <NA> 0/1
#3 0/0  0/1 0/0
```

With the first line we create a lookup table in which each element of `zero.zero` and `zero.one` is coupled with the desired replacement. Then, in the second line we perform the same operation on each column of `mydf` through `lapply`. This operation consists in finding where each element of the column stands in the column `values` of our lookup table. Then we take the corresponding `ind` value. We assign the result of `lapply` back to `mydf` (via `mydf[]<-`) to keep the `data.frame` structure of `mydf`.

Hope this clarifies a little.

**Data**

```
mydf<-structure(list(Ap = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), 
Bp = structure(c(2L, NA, 1L), .Label = c("AG", "AT"), class = "factor"), 
Cp = structure(c(2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("G", "GA", "GT"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Ap", 
"Bp", "Cp"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks. could you please explain this line: `mydf[]<-lapply(mydf,function(x) tab$ind[match(x,tab$value)])`.

Comment: @MAPK I made an edit. See if it is clearer now. Glad it helped.

Comment: Thanks! Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use indexing by replicating '0/0' and '0/1' and setting the names as 'zero.zero' and 'zero.one'

```
res <- mydf
v1 <- c(setNames(rep('0/0', length(zero.zero)), 
      zero.zero ), setNames(rep('0/1', length(zero.one)), zero.one ))
res[] <-  v1[as.matrix(mydf)]
res
#   Ap   Bp  Cp
#1 0/0  0/1 0/1
#2 0/0 <NA> 0/1
#3 0/0  0/1 0/0
```